# Is it possible to have a http client open another connection to the server or other users?

Tags: http, browser, client

I would like to make a browser based game with multiple gamers in the same environment.
So if I did a first person shooter type of game would a client be able to open a udp connection with the server?

Comment: How else would a client open a connection, but to make one to the server?  Yes, a web application can open connections to a server or other users, but to other users only if their application is a server.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a browser open a connection to any location you like but you cannot make a browser act as a server reliably (if at all).

You will need to have a server to receive/broadcast information